# Java: how to store sparse data efficiently

Tags: java, data-structures, sparse-matrix

I have more than a 1 billion items with approximatelly 1000 columns (a matrix). But for 95% columns unique values ratio is less than a percent, so this data could be classified as *sparse data*.

What is an effient and prod-ready solution for storing such a data in Java?

Comment: what operations do you need to perform on this data?

Comment: Well, use sparse files?

Comment: @DavidSoroko Store and retrive. Nothing more. Everything else is done via indices anyway.

Comment: Can you load the whole thing onto the heap?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've thought this through. If you really have billions of rows, even if you find a mechanism to store your sparse matrix efficiently you may well have problems holding that much data in memory anyway.

You could, however, use a simple map whose key is a `Pair` which holds the row and column for the datum.

```
public class Pair<P, Q> {

    public final P p;
    public final Q q;

    public Pair(P p, Q q) {
        this.p = p;
        this.q = q;
    }

    // TODO: Implement equals and hashCode.
}

class Datum {
}
// My sparse database.
Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Datum> data = new HashMap<>();
```

This would use close to minimal storage but does not necessarily solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think `HashTable` would be best option to do so ... `key-value` pair is efficient for same `value` i.e. one `key` for multiple `value`s.